# Can an insectoid race have a flexible exoskeleton?

Tags: aliens, xenobiology, insectoid

I'm fond of a insect race in a videogame, and want to base a race off of them, or write a fan fiction, but they flex a bit in the torso, and I wasn't sure...
Hope this makes sense.  :)

Animated picture below :D   Space pirate from Metroid.

[image: 1]

[image]

I added a smaller version, so you guys can see more details.  :)

Comment: Welcome to the site, LucineAura! Just for completeness, would you mind including the species you have in mind? It may provide additional details answerers can use.

Comment: How flexible? For maximal flexibility an insectoid could have overlapping plates of chitin, sort of like an armadillo.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

The biological feature you're looking for is called **segmentation.**

Arthropod exoskeletons have very defined functional units broken down into groups called **tagma**. These tagma are groups of segments such as the thorax, the head, the abdomen, etc. Each of these groups are connected by joints.

After all, the word *arthropoda* means "jointed legs."

It doesn't necessarily have to be an insectoid creature but insects are among the arthropods along with other creatures like crustaceans and arachnids. The material **chitin** (which is a polymer) connects the joints in these creatures, and it's noted for being very flexible and durable.

In regards to your flexibility in the torso region, I found in *New Zealand Journal of Zoology (1986)* a detailed maneuver of a female jumping spider called the *twist lunge*.

> > This usually happened when the female's abdomen was rotated and the male either had his palp engaged or was scraping with his palp. The female then suddenly twist lunged by rotating her cephalothorax toward the male (i.e., moving her cephalothorax into alignment with her abdomen) simultaneously making scooping motions with her legs, and moving her extended fangs toward the male.

Flexibility as described above is something you want to look for when trying to make creatures like this, since it utilizes [anatomical terms of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_motion) (Flexion, abduction, elevation, rotation, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the information, I really appreciate it.  :)   And thanks for the edit too.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, so the torso of the alien in the pic I posted, is made of chitin then?  It appears that there is a sliding motion of the torso as he breathes, moves, that's what I'm wondering about most of all.  Thanks for the description of the spider however, that is something I can look up later, maybe I can find a video.

Comment: @LucineAura The torso would be made of sclerotin and chitin. And yes, the individual segments do flex and bend.

Comment: Nitpick, but spiders aren't insects.  For an example of insect flexibility, see for instance the way dragonflies can bend their abdomen: http://www.arkive.org/emperor-dragonfly/anax-imperator/image-A24306.html

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, that's why I said that arachnids are included in arthropods. I didn't call the spider an insect. :/

Comment: @The Anathema: Yes, I was pointing out that the OP asked for "insectoid".

Comment: Is "insectoid" a correct label for this creature?  I just made assumptions because of the mandibles.  And kind of irrelevant to my original inquiry, but what do you guys think about the vent like formations on his head?  Do you think he breathes through those? Someone in a fan fiction once wrote 'heat vents' but not sure what that is.

Comment: @jamesqf Whether or not it's an insectoid doesn't really matter in terms of anatomical terms of motion - what matters is the material properties of chitin and sclerotin and their ability to flex and how tagma connect to each other. An insect is an arthropod with three pairs of legs - which is a definition that does not interfere with that fact. LucineAura - see previous statement about the number of legs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://blogs.cornell.edu/naturalistoutreach/files/2013/09/Exoskeletons-1dvznk6.pdf),

> The exoskeleton of insects is primarily made of proteins (sclerotin) and chitin
>   (polysaccharide molecules), which are interwoven and linked together to form strong
>   but **flexible** bundles.

The question here is how flexible you want the exoskeleton would be. Also, it would be nice if you provided the fictional video game insect species you were thinking of as FrostFyre requested in the comments. I'll update my answer once you do.

Comment: Done :D  Hope it's correct to my question though XD I try and understand things, but I could have defined something entirely different.